# Difference between named field and named column in datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

What is the difference bewteen the two below please?

```
var dtime = (DateTime)datatable[0]["SomeDateTime"];
var dtime = datatable[0].field<DateTime>("SomeDateTime");
```

EDIT
and this:

```
var dtime = Convert.ToDateTime(datatable[0]["SomeDateTime"]);
```

Comment: What is `datatable`? Because if it's a `DataTable` that won't compile. Don't provide pseudo code but compiling code (or the code that doesn't compile if that's the issue)..

Comment: Probably you are talking about a DataRowCollection. Please us a less confusing name for your variables.

Comment: It is a datatable and it does compile without errors. the only error I get is cast exceptions. Yes, by indexing a datatable with [0] it is in fact a datarow, I can change this but I dont think this is confusing

Comment: A `DataTable` has no default indexer method so you cannot write `datatable[0]` but only `datatable.Rows[0]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that the first uses an explicit cast by yourself whereas the second casts behind the scenes in the `DataRow` extension method [`Field`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891(v=vs.110).aspx).

So if the datetime-column can contain null-values you would use `DateTime?`:

```
DateTime? dtime = datatable.Rows[0].Field<DateTime?>("SomeDateTime");
```

So i would suggest to use [`Field`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891(v=vs.110).aspx). It's strongly typed(hides the cast) and supports nullable types. The explicit cast via `(TypeName)` is also less readable.

Comment: thanks Tim. So if the datatable contains nulls only the field would work?

Answer (score 1):

In the first line

```
var dtime = (DateTime)datatable[0]["SomeDateTime"];
```

you use the indexer property that returns an `object`. So you need to cast it yourself to the actual type you expect the object to be.

The second case

```
var dtime = datatable[0].Field<DateTime>("SomeDateTime");
```

calls the generic extension method `Field<T>` that tries to do the casting for you and returns the type you specified (so `DateTime` in your example).

You can inspect the different implementation in the reference source for the [indexer](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Data/R/9b399edb5e53cb56.html) and the [`Field<T>()` extension method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.DataSetExtensions/System/Data/DataRowExtensions.cs,ee33bac2abcfb06e)

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between the examples given is the method of conversion

`(Type)` takes what ever type you have and forces it to become that type, erroring it not suitible

`<Type>` is passing in a generic type for the implementation of field to use in its typeless definition, which means that there is behind the scenes logic helping you convert

and `Convert.ToType()` is using the converter class to do the conversion, as its call required types to be compatible with the IConvertable interface this means someone has put some thought into making that type convertable which mean your likely to get a successful result

otherwise you are just using different means to access the named field (either the this property or the field method